# Reporting Services 403 error

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I've recently updated an application to the 3.5 framework (from 2.0). The app links to Reporting Services (2005) remotely via an URL. This all works fine locally but when deployed to the dev server (win 2003) I'm getting a 403 error when attempting to call the report server.

"You are not authorized to view this page
...

HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden "

This just started happening after the 3.5 framework was installed, I've tried various security settings but can't get this to work again.

Does anyone know what security needs to be set or what I need to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I should answer myself or just comment but anyway.

Found the (or at least a) solution from another post. Apparently the reporting services root directory can get corrupted - how is not clear - but I deleted the ReportServer virtual directory and recreated it with the Reporting Services Configuration tool.

It's working again, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

When you say call the report server, what do you mean specifically? Access the Report Manager using this url: www.myserver.com/reports   ?

The main reason is, that locally you are authenticated implicitly as the user you're logged on to the server. Accessing the server remotely in the browser, does not necessarily authenticate you. Do you have anonymous authentication enabled in IIS on the server? If so, you are authenticated as a public anonymous/guest user and have not access to the report server. By disabling anonymous authentication, you will be prompted for username/password to authenticate.

Comment: The report link in the app points to the reportserver url - "http://devserver/ReportServer?..." which then opens up the report in a new browser window using the built in html viewer.